# Make a program to run on a specific network interface?

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, iptables

Short question: How can you make only one specific program run off `wlan0` and leave everything else to run off the ethernet?

Long question: I've been using my Raspberry Pi for a while now and I love it! One of it's major uses is running [homebridge](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge). However, I would really like to use it for a few more things that require a stronger network connection in the form of ethernet. To cut short, whilst homebridge works perfectly when there is no ethernet plugged in, the second the ethernet is plugged in it stops working. Furthermore, when I reset homebridge and re-add it, it only works for about 30 minutes before cutting out once again. To clarify, everything else works perfectly on ethernet such as SSH, Remote Desktop etc. Also, I have done some digging around on forums to try and find a solution both to the homebridge problem but also on how to do what I've asked but I couldn't find anything that worked for me. Therefore, would love to find out if there is a way of having the ethernet plugged in but have only homebridge ignore it and use `wlan0` instead? Is there a simple prefix that can be added to the usual `homebridge` command to do this or is it a little bit trickier?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: Routing is not enough to pull it off (even using separate routing tables, which is provided out of the box with iproute2)?

Comment: @eftshift0 Thanks for your response! That's a shame; any ideas come to mind that _might_ work? Would you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well.... I was just asking you if using iproute2 was not enough. Playing with different routing tables could be an option. You can set up traffic to use a separate routing table that sends traffic through wlan, for example. http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry pi kernel supports network namespaces, so you can start your program in a separate network namespase using [`ip netns`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html). If you only set up `wlan0` in that namespace, your program won't have a choice.

Prior to namespaces support, the standard solution was to create a special user which would run the program, and define a routing table entry which redirects the traffic of that user to a different network interface. Or, if `homebridge` always uses the same port, you can redirect its traffic based on the port number. I suppose this is what @eftshift0 refers to in his comment. It's still a viable option if you're more familiar with routing than namespaces.